# Is it possible to get the value for a key in a Hashtable without iteration?

Tags: .net, hashtable, key, iteration

Using .NET 3.5, is there a way to retrieve a value from Hashtable corresponding to the key without iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

var value = hashtable[key]; ?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pradeep.tiwari/PradeepTiwariHashtable11072006072247AM/PradeepTiwariHashtable.aspx

Comment: And depending which hash class you're using (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary) you can use TryGetValue() to avoid an exception if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Thats correct, don't forget to either use a .TryGetValue() or use .Contains() before attempting to retrieve the value.